# EF Core - switch to SQL Server with existing MySQL migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I cloned an ASP.NET Core 2 project with git and it uses Entity Framework Core with MySQL database.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

Is it possible for me to contribute on this project but use my local SQL Server instead of MySQL and don't change this on source?

I tried changing `UseMySql` to `UseSqlServer` with the right connection string but it threw exception in migrations.

Comment: It is possible but half your battle would be spent ensuring you keep your Sql Server references out of the repo.  Easily done in git by not tracking certain files but the hard one will be Startup.cs.  You would also have to generate migrations for Sql Server and keep them in a separate assembly, likely with it's own DbContext.  How much do you want to contribute to this project when you add this overhead for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily. If the application wasn't designed with this scenario in mind, you may have to update a lot of it to work on Microsoft SQL Server.

If you're just trying to avoid installing MySQL locally, I've found using Docker ideal for that. (See the [mysql/mysql-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) image.)